# Problem proving type equality when using match types in type functions

Tags: scala, scala-3, match-types

Given

```
type Bool
type True <: Bool
type False <: Bool
```

And

```
type Neg [B <: Bool] <: Bool =
  B match
    case True => False
    case False => True
```

This compiles (no surprises here):

```
summon [Neg [True] =:= False]
```

But this, surprisingly, does not:

```
summon [Neg [False] =:= True]
```

It seems to depend on order of cases in type match - if I change the order of branches in `Neg`, `Neg [False]` will work, but `Neg [True]` won't?!

Scala 3.0.0-RC3

**EDIT:**

This works as expected (with `Neg` unchanged):

```
trait Bool
class True extends Bool
class False extends Bool
```

This too:

```
trait Bool
object True extends Bool
object False extends Bool
type True = True.type
type False = False.type
```

Comment: This is because `False` could also be `True`, since you only say `<:`. Since the compiler cannot guarantee that a `False` is not a `True`, it just takes the first case every time. See what happens if you make them final classes instead.